# exports is not defined when running compiled typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I am trying to take my first steps into working with typescript and I've run into an issue when trying to run my application.

I get the error `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

the code I have is quite simple:

```
// --src/changeset.ts
export enum ChangeAction {
  ADD,
  DELETE,
  MODIFY
}

export class Changeset {
  constructor(
    public version: Number,
    public content: String,
    public path: String,
    public action: ChangeAction
  ) {}
}

// --src/index.ts
import { Changeset, ChangeAction } from "./changeset";

const set = new Changeset(0, "Hello world", "/dev/null", ChangeAction.ADD);
set.version = 0;

console.log("Hello World! " + set.version);

// --tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "build"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

running `tsc`, it compiles and seems to work without any real issues, however when I try to run it with `node build/index.js` it crashes with this

```
build/index.js:2
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                      ^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

It feels like I am missing something quite obvious, but I can't really seem to put my finger on it, so what am I missing?

Comment: Please use that code {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "*": [
          "node_modules/*"
        ]
      }
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*"
    ]
  }

Comment: no luck unfortunately :/
I get the same error even with that tsconfig

Comment: can you share your project ?

Comment: Replace the `"outDir": "dist"` with `"outDir": "build"` from the example @MaheshBhatnagar posted, or run it with `node dist/index.js`. You're probably still running the previously built code.

Comment: https://github.com/munHunger/soft-sync
I did update the `outDir`, so it is pointing to what I assume is the correct file

Comment: Which `node` version are you using? `node --version` Also, which version of `typescript` are you using?

Comment: running version v13.3.0

Comment: regarding typescript version: `"dependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.7.4"
  }`

Comment: Please user node version v12.13.0

Comment: when run your code that run correctly not got error

Comment: Remove `"type": "module"` from package.json.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to have enabled [Node's ES modules](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field) by setting `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`, but your tsconfig tells typescript to emit code compatible with CommonJS.

Either remove `"type": "module"`, or configure tsconfig to emit code targeting ES modules.