# Electron and Typescript - Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

I have an electron app that is written in typescript. Here is the minimum code:

`someModule.ts`:

```js
function someFunction() {}

export default someFunction;
```

`main.ts`:

```js
import someFunction from "./someModule";

someFunction();
```

`index.html`:

```html
...

<script defer src="main.js"></script>

...
```

`index.ts` (package entry which starts with `npm start`):

```js
import { BrowserWindow, app } from "electron";

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }
    });

    win.loadFile("./index.html");
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if(process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
})
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["DOM"], 
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  }
}
```

When I run the app (by `npx tsc && node index.js` command (which is `npm start` in package scripts)) the console in electron window gives an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at main.js:5:23
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: perhaps something to do with your tsconfig.json (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined)

Comment: @UsithaIndeewara sorry didn't read your code closely enough. You need to set your module type to commonjs in your tsconfig, and make sure you do **not** have type: module in your package.json. Electron is node.js, it doesn't support the ESM syntax for .js files. See also [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696265/exports-is-not-defined-when-running-compiled-typescript)

Comment: My tsconfig already has `"module": "commonjs"` and I don't have `"type": "module"` in package.json. But the error occurs. @JaredSmith @AlainBUFERNE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding this in the `index.html` file:

```
<script>
    require("./main.js");
</script>
```

instead of `<script src="main.js"></script>`